# ¿Como deshabilito el touch de una pantalla desde c#?

Tags: c#, screen

Tengo una pantalla Elo touch, desde su software si se puede deshabilitar, pero necesito deshabilitarlo desde c#. Como puedo hacer eso

Comment: Saludos Jesus Jose ¿Has visto la documentación de ese software?

Comment: Como dice @fredyfx es cuestión que leas el manual de dicho software para ver que entrada debes modificar. Encontré la siguiente pregunta planteada en SO, quizás te ayude a orientarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339464/how-to-enable-and-disable-touch-screen-on-windows-ce-or-windows-mobile